# BrowserEngine: 29 - UI element not found in Silk Performer

Tags: silk-performer

I have recorded my application using internet explorer in Silk performer using BDLT approach as this protocol by default it will consider for recording IE only, but my application is comapatable with Chrome. While replaying the script using chrome getting below error.

Error   VUser-Profile1_1    localhost   65  00:01:19    BrowserClick    BrowserEngine: 29 - UI element not found

The chrome window is getting opened and application URL is also loading. But it is not moving further and facing that issue.

Answer (score 0):

That error could be related to the synchronization mode used to recognize when has an action finished and the next one can be performed.

You can try setting sync mode to HTML instead of AJAX around the functions where the error occur:

```
BrowserSetOption(BROWSER_OPT_SYNC_MODE, SYNC_MODE_HTML);  
/*The actions where the error occur*/
BrowserSetOption(BROWSER_OPT_SYNC_MODE, SYNC_MODE_AJAX);
```